# Has the /sys/bus/usb/ the same structure in all Linux distributions

Tags: usb, serial-port

I am porting mono app from Windows to Linux. The app communicates with external board. This board is visible as three virtual serial ports. Every plays a different role.

The app is automatically detecting those ports. Can I relay on the structure and information in the /sys/bus/usb/ ie are they the same in the different Linux distros?

Comment: It should be the same if kernel is Linux. Keep in mind that there is distros that use FreeBSD's kernel (Debian's KFreeBSD). Useful info regarding Linux kernel: https://superuser.com/questions/794198/directory-sys-in-linux

Comment: What are you looking for in the /sys/bus/usb directory?  If you need to know which serial port controls which function, you may want to make a `udev` rule to create a symlink(e.g. `/dev/function1 -> /dev/ttyUSB0`)

Comment: @rm5248 Trying to make it "configuration free". Actually I iterate through all devices, check PID/VID interface numbers (it is a composite device) and detect which one is which one.